Submit Button Is Navigating Away From the Page
I'm currently building a website using Next.js (React) and Strapi, and I've encountered an issue while setting up the newsletter subscription form.
Here are the problems I'm facing:

useState Issue: The useState for hasSignedUp isn’t behaving as expected. When hasSignedUp is set to true, everything works fine: the <h4> displays correctly if email.length > 0, and the page refreshes when the submit button is clicked. However, when hasSignedUp is set to false by default (as it should be), the functionality breaks. I’m not sure why this is happening.

Page Refresh: The page is refreshing after form submission, even though I’ve used preventDefault() in the form’s onSubmit handler.

Unexpected Navigation: When I click submit, the browser navigates to a new URL: "http://localhost:3000/blog?email=fsfssfsdf", where "fsfssfsdf" is the input I typed before submitting. The console logs also show this navigation ("http://localhost:3000/blog?email=fsfssfsd"). There is no action associated with this input, so not sure what is happening.


This is my SubscribeToNewsletter component:
"use client";
import { useState } from "react"; // Creating a use state to track what the user is typing in the input section

const SubscribeToNewsletter = () => {
  console.log(" SubscribeToNewsletter component rendered ");

  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [hasSignedUp, setHasSignedUp] = useState(false);

  const onChange = (e) => {
    console.log("Email input changed:", e.target.value);
    setEmail(e.target.value);
  };

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("On submit has been clicked");
    console.log("Current email:", email);

    if (email.length) {
      console.log("Email is valid, updating hasSignedUp state");
      setHasSignedUp(true);
    } else {
      console.log("Email is empty or invalid");
    }
  };

  return (
    <section className="newsletter">
      {hasSignedUp ? (
        <h4 className="newsletter__thanks">
          Thank you for signing up to our newsletter !
        </h4>
      ) : (
        <>
          <div className="newsletter__info">
            <h4>Subscribe to our newsletter</h4>
            <p className="copy">
              Unlock Exclusive Insights and Stay In the Know – Subscribe to Our
              Newsletter Today to always stay in touch
            </p>
          </div>
          <form className="newsletter__form" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
            <input
              id="email"
              name="email"
              type="text"
              className="newsletter__email input"
              placeholder="Enter your E-mail address"
              value={email}
              onChange={onChange}
            />
            <button
              type="submit"
              className="newsletter__subscribe btn btn--medium btn--turquoise"
            >
              SUBSCRIBE
            </button>
          </form>
        </>
      )}
    </section>
  );
};

export default SubscribeToNewsletter;

This is my main blog page component, on which the SubscribeToNewsletter component should be rendered:
import HighlightArticle from "../_components/Blog/HighlightArticle";
import SubscribeToNewsletter from "../_components/Blog/SubscribeToNewsletter";

export default function Page() {
  console.log(" The BLOG page has been mounted");

  const highlightArticleData = {
    headline: "3 tips for a super fast takeoff",
    excerpt:
      "Improving your take-off phase in surfing is a fundamental step toward riding waves with more confidence and style. Improving your take-off phase is a gradual process, and it may take time to master. Be patient, stay committed to practice, and enjoy the journey of becoming a better surfer. With dedication and persistence, you'll see progress and have more enjoyable rides. Here is how:",
    slug: "takeoff",
    featuredImage: "/assets/hero-experience.png",
  };

  return (
    <main className="blog-page ">
      <HighlightArticle data={highlightArticleData} />
      <SubscribeToNewsletter />
    </main>
  );
}

What I've tried so far, to fix the issue:

I've been troubleshooting an issue with my useState setup, and here’s what I’ve observed:

I changed the useState default value from false to true to see if it would render in the browser:


const [hasSignedUp, setHasSignedUp] = useState(true);

With this setup, when I submit an email through the form, the <h4> element renders the thank you message as expected. However, if I click submit without entering any text (email.length < 0), the page reloads.

To narrow down the issue, I added several console.log statements. Only the first one (console.log(" SubscribeToNewsletter component rendered ")) is appearing in the VSCode terminal, but I’m not seeing any logs from the others in the browser’s console. Despite this, I am getting a 200 OK response from the network.

I even tried deleting my existing component and creating a new SubscribeToNewsletter component from scratch, but the issue persists.

I also tested with a minimal example, but it didn’t display the input value in the console log:


"use client";
import { useState } from "react";

const TestInput = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setText(e.target.value);
    console.log("Input value:", e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <input
      type="text"
      value={text}
      onChange={handleChange}
      placeholder="Type something..."
    />
  );
};

export default TestInput; 


An error in your javascript could cause the preventDefault() to not fire. Are there any errors in your dev console? "Get" is the default action for a form.

The e.preventDefault will fire on submit as the first thing. If it was later in that function then yes. So it is not the onsubmit - it is more likely that the event handler is not called at all

Try this. If the console.log is not showing, then you have a native submit or similar: const onSubmit = (e) => {   console.log("Form submission triggered");   e.preventDefault();

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

There are unfortunately no errors in my dev console. Or in the browser console.
I'd already had a console log for the e.preventDefault, and unfortunately nothing is being displayed in the browser's console. Not really sure where to go from here

@mplungjan has some good suggestions; have you tried those?

If there is no console.log from the preventDefault, then your code is not running. Do you perhaps have a "prettyform plugin" or something else that takes over submission?

@mplungjan i've tried placing the console log in front of the e.preventDefault();
unfortunately i'm not getting anything logged. The page keeps being refreshed, with the url displaying the content submitted from the form => http://localhost:3000/blog?email=fdsfsfsd.
I'm sorry, what do you mean by "prettyform plugin" ?

I see strapi is a headless cms, so I assume this is not the case there. Possibly the strapi does not even read your code if it does not handle DOM event handlers

Indeed, Strapi isn't reading the code, so can't use it to get, post, delete info, until this bit is fixed :(

Hi all ! So I fixed it !
I deleted the node_module folder and reinstalled it (npm i) and launched it once more using npm run dev and the code works  - Everything is logging and the email is being sent to strapi !
Thanks for all of your help !
